# GDK-05043 Not a valid month when import exported table

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to copy some data from db1 to db2 using sql developer.
For this i exported the data from db1 to csv file.
When i try to import it to db2 i get GDK-05043 Not a valid month.

[My date format and input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM0K7.png)

NLS settings in db2 are the same as in db1.

[NLS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkJni.png)

What am I doing wrong?
It would be great if you'd be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Click on the date value in the preview window, does the warning go away?

Comment: Yes, but in this case sql developer does not insert data to table after finish button .And it does not generate any log files. sql developer version is 17.2.0.188.1159

Comment: What does the CSV file look like?

Comment: Switch the import method to Insert Script, are the statements malformed?

Comment: [My csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q45o6.png)

Comment: @thatjeffsmith After switching metod to Insert Script nothing has changed. I have not inserted data in table and logs or message about success or fail insert too.

Comment: INSERT SCRIPT doesn't insert data, it generates the INSERT statements - show them here so we can see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on another pc. Records imported successful. So it is problem with my sql developer. Thanks everybody for help.

Comment: If you want to know the problem, share what you did on both machines and post the generated script